# Plus equals with subclass in python

Tags: python, subclass

I want to be able to use `+=` with subclasses in python. That is, I want to be able to append to the value in the superclass with `+=` in python:

```
class a():
  a = 2
class b(a):
  a += 4

b = b()

assert b.a == 6
```

I know I can do this like

```
class b(a):
  a = a.a + 4
```

but I would like to do it in a more concise way. Also, I can't seem to get the above to work with `super()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need this?

Comment: Do you actually want class variables instead of instance variables here? If so, why? Also, it really doesn't help you to understand things when you reuse the same names to mean different things—`b = b()` is particularly bad, because you've rebound `b` from the class `b` to an instance of that class, and no longer have any direct reference to the class `b` at all; `a.a` isn't as bad, but it's still confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phil Frost is right that you can't do it using the direct syntax you seem to want.  However, you could use a class decorator.  This runs after the class is defined, so it can access variables of the superclass.  However, you'll have to use slightly more cumbersome syntax.  Here's one possibility:

```
class InheritedPlus(object):
    def __init__(self, toAdd):
        self.toAdd = toAdd

def addInherited(cls):
    for attr, val in vars(cls).iteritems():
        if isinstance(val, InheritedPlus):
            setattr(cls, attr, getattr(super(cls, cls), attr)+val.toAdd)
    return cls

class A(object):
    x = 2

@addInherited
class B(A):
    x = InheritedPlus(3)

>>> B.x
5
```

This doesn't let you use `+=`, but it does let you get the effectof creating class attributes in a subclass that are based on the superclass's values.  With some more cleverness you could create a general-purpose `Inherited()` class that implemented the various operators and stores the operands, to allow things like `x = Inherited() + 3`.

I think there are legitimate use cases for wanting to access superclass attributes at class-definition time, and this approach can work for that.  If you just have a simple case like the one in your example, though, it's probably not worth this level of complexity, and you should just use `a.a + 4` explicitly.

Comment: interesting solution ... hard time seeing a real use case for it ... and it certainly doesnt feel pythonic (explicit > implicit) ... but still +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It's definitely a bit peculiar.  But this is still pretty explicit, because you still have to explicitly indicate (with `InheritedPlus`) that you want to access the superclass value and modify it.  It just doesn't make you repeat the literal superclass name.  It's not really any less explicit than a normal `super` call.

Answer (score 6):

You can not do what you want. These are intentional aspects of Python's design.

You can not do this:

```
class a():
    a = 2
class b(a):
    a += 4
```

because there is no `a` in scope on the last line. You must be explicit about the namespace where `a` can be found.

You will not find a way to make it work with `super`. The reason is that `super` needs at least a type as a parameter, but at the point which you want to use it (inside the definition of `b`), `b` doesn't exist yet. So, you can't give it to `super()`.

In the end, you answered your own question. You are doing the right thing, because [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).